# Need to know which is the correct way of implement constructor function

Tags: javascript

Need to know which is the correct way of implementing the constructor function from these two options.

```
var Dog=function(name,bread)
{
    return {

        name:name,
        bread:bread

    }

}

function Dog(name,bread)
{
    var new_object= this;

    new_object.name=name;
    new_object.bread=bread;
}
```

Comment: The answer, is of course, it depends. Both are fine, although the first would be named a 'factory function' rather than a constructor.

Comment: The first is what we call a *factory*, not a constructor. The second uses a completely unnecessary, an [implicitly global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) variable instead of `this`

Comment: The are no constructor function implementations in your snippets.

Comment: @Bergi, Corrected the typo missed adding var.

Comment: @all , reason for this question is that,have came across this two ways of construct function which does the same thing, need to know significance of each. Intent was somebody who knows javascript well can guide me. Excuss me if this question sound stupid.

Answer (score 1):

The is not one correct way to do that in JavaScript. Refer to this answer to see the different patterns that you can use to program in an object-oriented way in JavaScript:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30148923/1566187

Comment: thanks for reference

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do with it, but if you're looking for a simple constructor I'd recommend

```
function dog(name,breed) {
    this.name = name;
    this.breed = breed;
}
```

This way you can create new objects easily using that constructor:

```
var Dog = new dog("Jacky", "Corgi");
var Puppy = new dog("T-Rex", "Yorkshire");
```

Hope this helps. :)